# cocos 2d x capture screenshot and display instantly in ios c++

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I want to capture the screenshot during game and and to display that captured image on app I am using cocos 2d-x v2.3 c++ version. 
How it can be possible ?
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling maybe? Break down your problem into steps: 1. capture screenshot 2. display screenshot. Then Google each one

Comment: @LordZsolt yes I have been googling it since 2 hours and google in same manner as you have suggested me. I only found code for cocos 2dx-v3 But I was working on v2 I want version 2 code

Answer (score 3):

You can capture screen shot by using `CCRenderTexture` and following is the code：

```
CCRenderTexture* texture = CCRenderTexture::create((int)visibleSize.width, (int)visibleSize.height);
texture->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2));
texture->begin();
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->visit();
texture->end();
texture->saveToFile("screenshot.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
```

But I don't know how to retrieve image from here :) If any one know then please also tell me.

Comment: win32: Debug.win23/screenshot.png Android: /data/data/com.packagename/files/screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

I implemented above code for screenshot in cocos2dx 2.2.6 but BAD_ACCESS genrate on  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->visit(); line.